# onclick pass variables to ajax

Tags: html, ajax

AI have an expanding box, which contains some information, what I want to do and not sure if it is possible is that when somebody clicks on the link (shown below)

```
 <a href="#" class="expandLink">View Job Description</a>
```

it passes a variable to Ajax and then have that update a mysql table to say the job description has been viewed.

Now I know the link above is just a link which triggers some javascript to expand the box and so just after some advice on how I can achieve this?.

I have other code which passes variables to ajax but through a form, and so I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: onlick? sounds... interesting and unsanitary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one using Jquery:

after the clicking the link the ajax request will be sent to the specified url.

ulr i.e. where your script will excute.
store all result in variable and print at the end of page.

Usins variable "data" you can get that result.

$(".expandLink").click(function(){

$.post("url",function(data,status){

$(div).html(data);
}

});